# How to access app running in localhost when testcafe running in docker container?

Tags: docker, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I run testcafe in a custom docker container and I have the web app running in different docker container (or docker-compose). If I use the app from the web browser I go to the localhost:8080

How can I access the app from testcafe docker container?

```
> docker run -ti mycustom/testcafe firefox /tests/*

Error details:
Failed to find a DNS-record for the resource at "http://localhost:8080/".
```

I tried to add `--network=network-name` but it didn't help.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] for what you're trying to do?  When you say "running in localhost", which localhost is it – the physical host's localhost, the same Docker container's localhost, a different container or host's localhost?

Comment: Thank you for the answer and questions. Edited my original question. So, I've the app running in docker and run testcafe tests in the other container.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to explicitly configure the network with docker-compose. For the solution without docker-compose, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49806177/connect-from-one-docker-container-to-the-other-one) thread.